# how can i bind this value to the src attribute in a dynamic image on vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lightbox

I'm new with vue and I'm learning so my code can be very simple, and I would like to make a kind of lightbox, my problem is that I don't know how to link the imgSrc attribute to the image that is clicked when the effect is activated lightbox

Template:

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    <div class="image" v-for="(imagenes, index) in imgBanos" :key="index">
      <img :src="imagenes.img" :id="imagenes.id" @click="change">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="popup-imag" v-show="show">
    <span @click="reverse">&times;</span>
    <img :src="imgSrc">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      show: false,
      imgSrc: "",
      imgBanos: [{
          id: 2,
          img: require("../assets/si/2.jpeg")
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          img: require("../assets/si/3.png")
        },
        ...
      ],

    }
  },
  methods: {
    change() {
      this.show = true
    },
    reverse() {
      this.show = false
    }
  }
}
```

I want to link the imgSrc element with the clicked image coming from the imgBanos.img source

I tried giving each image an index, but I don't know how vue recognizes the image that has been selected with the click

Answer (score 0):

Just update your `change()` method so that you can pass in the `src` (or whatever data you need):

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in imgBanos" :key="index">
  <img :src="image.img" @click="showImageInPopup(image)">
</div>
```

Then you can use it in your callback:

```
showImageInPopup(image) {
  this.imgSrc = image.src
  this.show = true         
}
```

Comment: I know I have to link it that way, my question is how do I reference the src within the change method to assign its value to the imgSrc

Comment: ```
change(imagenes) {
            this.imgSrc = imagenes.src
            this.show = true
             
        }
```

Comment: Check the updated answer, I think this is what you asked for (right?)